# Conformal mapping maps the unit disc in a convex domain.

Tags: complex-analysis

Statement of the problem:

*For the conformal mapping $f:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ , we suppose that the domain $f(\mathbb{D})$ is convex. Prove that for $\mathbb{D}_r=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|<r\}$ the domain $f(\mathbb{D}_r)$ is convex*

My approach: I considered the function 
$$g(z)=f^{-1}(tf(z)+(1-t)f(0)), t\in[0,1]$$
This function is holomorphic , maps the unit disc to itself, and $g(0)=0$. So we can apply Schwarz's lemma. After using it, we have that
$$|f^{-1}(tf(z)+(1-t)f(0))|\leq|z|$$
which means that
$$g(\mathbb{D}_r)\subset \mathbb{D}_r,\Longrightarrow f^{-1}(tf(z)+(1-t)f(0))\in \mathbb{D}_r \Longrightarrow tf(z)+(1-t)f(0) \in f(\mathbb{D}_r)$$
so all of these line segments belong to our domain, but in order to show that the domain is convex I need to prove that this happens for every $f(z),f(w)$ and not only for $f(z),f(0).$
At this stage I considered the function
$$\phi^{-1}\circ g\circ \phi:\mathbb{D}\to \mathbb{D}, \phi(z)=\frac{z-w}{1-\bar{w}z},z,w \in \mathbb{D}$$ and i applied Schwarz's lemma again and I tried to prove it for all $z,w \in \mathbb{D}$ but got stuck.

I would be grateful if you give me just the smallest possible hint and not a whole solution.

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *Study's theorem*. You can find a proof, e.g., in Duren's book *Univalent functions*. If we may assume that $f$ is defined and $C^1$ on the closed disc $\bar D$ the proof is quite easy: Look at the images  $\gamma_r$ of concentric circles  $\partial D_r$ $\,(0<r\leq1)$, given by
$$\gamma_r:\quad t\mapsto w(t):=f\bigl(r e^{it}\bigr)\qquad(0\leq t\leq2\pi)\ .\tag{1}$$
Such a curve $\gamma_r$ is convex **iff** its tangent argument $$t\mapsto\theta(t):={\rm arg}\bigl(w'(t)\bigr)={\rm Im}\bigl(\log w'(t)\bigr)$$ is monotonically increasing. Therefore the convexity condition amounts to
$$\theta'(t)={\rm Im}\left({w''(t)\over w'(t)}\right)\geq0\ .\tag{2}$$
If $f(D)$, hence $\gamma_1$, is convex then $(2)$ translates via $(1)$ into a condition involving $f'$, $f''$ on $\partial D$. The maximum principle then guarantees that this condition holds througout $D$, and this in turn implies that all $\gamma_r$ are convex.

Comment: I searched and found it was Study's theorem. I fully understand your answer ! Thanks for that. I found a later paper though were it states that Radό proved the theorem using Schwarz's lemma. Do you have any idea on this ?

Comment: Found it. I was close , yet so far... Thanks for your insight